# Getting values from a text box which is defined in many dynamically generated user controls

Tags: c#, user-controls, textbox, dynamically-generated

I am developing a medical store application in c#. During its bill generation the following window is opened that adds an item using a dynamically generated user control called MediRow.
[image]
The MediRow consits of a text box for quantity. When the value of the text box changes the total amount label on the main window should sum the quantities entered in text boxes of all generated MediRow controls. I added the following code to a background worker that checks for all textbox values and add them up, but its not working.

```
double amt = 0;
            foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
            {
                amt = amt + long.Parse(((MediRow)c).Controls.Find("textBox1",true)[0].Text);
            }
            lblAmt.Text = amt.ToString();
```

Please tell me how to get those text box values dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I don't think that polling the rows is good idea. You should subscribe to the textboxes TextChanged events.
By the way, you probably want to use a NumericUpDown instead of a text box...

Comment: But in case of NumericUpDown how can I get the values of all NumericUpDowns generated dynamically

Comment: ur mixing double and long while adding,is that ok in ur code

Comment: ya thats ok but the problem is that the values from the textboxes are not fetched at runtime.

Comment: you are iterating the panel and what if the first control is not of type MediRow.Will the cast succeed?.are u getting any exceptions.

Comment: actually the panel can contain only MediRow controls.

Comment: I have been doing desktop application since years and believe me, using a grid is far better approach. It will really make your life easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose the TextBox values through **Public Properties**

**EDIT:**

```
class MyCustomItem 
{ 

  public string ItemName 
  { 
    get { return TxtName.Text; } 
  } 

  public string ItemQuantity 
  { 
    get { return TxtQuantity.Text; } 
  }


  // other logic here
}
```

Comment: Can you give me example on this